# callback function for advertise is not called

Tags: ros, callback, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a publisher node and I would like to get a callback when a subscriber connects. I followed the example in the [documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a2d81fe5562417931bd7634490c364473), but I get a compilation warning and no callback. For example, I start a `rostopic echo` before I launch my node, and I do receive the message, but the publisher is never notified that a subscriber connected.

Here is the warning:

In function `‘int main(int, char**)’: .../AppTestCallbackSubscription.cpp:20:88: warning: the address of ‘void connectCallback(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Waddress]`

Here is the code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

//typedef boost::function<void(const SingleSubscriberPublisher&)> SubscriberStatusCallback;
void connectCallback(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher& pub)
{
    ROS_INFO("Subscriber connected");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const std::string TOPIC_NAME = "/foo";
    
    ros::init(argc, argv, "MyPublisher");

    ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
    
    // None of these two lines triggers the callback
    //ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>(TOPIC_NAME, 10, connectCallback, ros::SubscriberStatusCallback(), ros::VoidConstPtr(), false);
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>(TOPIC_NAME, 10, connectCallback);
      
    // Gives time to the subscribers to connect
    ros::Time maxTime(ros::Time::now()+ros::Duration(1)); // Will wait at most 1000 ms
    while(ros::Time::now()<maxTime)
    {
        ros::spinOnce();
    }

    std_msgs::String msg;
    msg.data = "Hello World!";
    pub.publish(msg);
    
    ROS_INFO("Message published");

    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48312/callback-function-for-advertise-is-not-called/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the solution found by @Lorenz and fixed (in the documentation) by @Dirk Thomas.

An explicit type cast is required in front of the callback function:

Instead of: `handle.advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("my_topic", 1, connectCallback);`

Use: `handle.advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("my_topic", 1, (ros::SubscriberStatusCallback)connectCallback);`

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are passing the callback pointer address as the `bool latch` parameter (3rd parameter in the advertise function) and the compiler is telling you that this will always evaluate to true. Here's the [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options) where I got this from.

I'm not sure how to get the behavior you want, but what you did is definitely not the way to go.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-14**:
Wow. Good catch. I would say to get the right method selected, either specify all parameters or at least the disconnect callback. Maybe, adding a & in front of connectCallback could also help. Or an explicit type cast.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-14**:
I was also afraid of compiler ambiguity so I already tried passing in all parameters (commented out line above). No improvement though. Adding a & in front also did not work. However, an explicit type cast did the trick! @Lorenz, maybe you could write it as a new answer and I'll give you kudos :-)

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-14**:
Also, I'll file a ticket to update the documentation because it I did a copy-paste from it and it clearly didn't work

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-11-14**:
I put in this issue: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/23

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-14**:
I think the karma should go to @georgebrinbeiro :) Btw. I just tried and I guess the problem is that `SubscriberStatusCallback` is a boost::function and the compiler doesn't cast to it correctly. Explicitly creating the right type is better than casting: `SubscriberStatusCallback(connectCallback)`.